# How to convert text to date and sum to time by vba?

Tags: vba, excel

how are you? Look, I am opening a tab-delimited file which contains information about the day and the time when a sample was analysed. I'd like to sum time and date, in a way that would be possible to sort lines based on this information.

Time and date are stored as strings, in two different cells, just like:
Date: 29/11/2013
13:41:59:546

Because of this, I had to create a formula to remove "Date: " and to convert ":546" to milliseconds and add to the rest of the number. Unfortunately, even removing "Date: ", I can't convert "29/11/2013" to a number, considering that date is interpreted as a number by excel. It's interesting because with the workbook opened, if I select the cell with 29/11/2013 (after "Date: " being removed) and press F2, then enter, excel converts it to a number. Am I missing something when I am trying to do the same by vba?

My result should be a number that with the appropriate format

```
.numberformat="dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss.000"
```

should show 29/11/2013 13:41:59.546.

My function is:

```
Function DateTimeCustomFormat(TimeCell As Range, DateCell As Range, formatTime As String, formatDate As String)

    Dim ms As Double 'Means milliseconds
    Dim msTOday As Long 'Factor to convert ms to day (ms divided by all milliseconds in a day)

    msTOday = 86400000

    Select Case formatTime

        Case "hh:mm:ss:ms(xxx)"

            ms = Val(Right(TimeCell, 3)) / msTOday
                TimeCell = Left(TimeCell, Len(TimeCell) - 4) 
                    TimeCell.NumberFormat = "0.00" '"h:mm:ss.000"
                        TimeCell = TimeCell + ms

    End Select

        Select Case formatDate

        Case "Date: dd/mm/yyyy"

                DateCell = Right(DateCell, Len(DateCell) - 6)
                    DateCell.NumberFormat = "dd:mm:aaaa"
                        'DateCell = DateCell.Value * 1

    End Select

        DateTimeCustomFormat = TimeCell + DateCell


End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems as if you not really familiar with object datatypes such as Range and with what can a user defined function do and what not.

In your code you get the parameter TimeCell as Range but then you overwrite this with a string (`TimeCell = Left(TimeCell, Len(TimeCell) - 4)`) and then you try setting NumberFormat to this. A string has no NumberFormat ;-). Furthermore a user defined function cannot set NumberFormat to cells and it also cannot set cell values, if this was the goal of the above code line. It only can return a value. This value gets then the value of the cell, which contains the user defined function as a formula.

Same Problem with DateCell.

Your code should get the parts of the cell values which represents the time or the date as strings and then convert them to dates. Therefor some functions are useable.

Easy to use are TimeValue and DateValue. But these functions depend on the system settings for date and time format. So it may be that they don't get the right values. For the date for example with "06/07/2014" is not really clear if it is July the 06. or June the 07. This depends on the system date format settings.

A more general solution is to use TimeSerial and DateSerial. This is the better solution in my opinion because the formates are precisely defined.

```
Function DateTimeCustomFormat(TimeCell As Range, DateCell As Range, formatTime As String, formatDate As String) As Date

    Dim ms As Double 'Means milliseconds
    Dim msTOday As Long 'Factor to convert ms to day (ms divided by all milliseconds in a day)
    Dim sTime As String, sDate As String 'String parts of the given parameters
    Dim dTime As Date, dDate As Date 'Calculated datetime values of the given parameters

    msTOday = 86400000

    Select Case formatTime
        Case "hh:mm:ss:ms(xxx)"
            ms = Val(Right(TimeCell.Value, 3)) / msTOday
            sTime = Left(TimeCell.Value, Len(TimeCell.Value) - 4)
            'dTime = TimeValue(sTime) + ms 'please read help for TimeValue
            dTime = TimeSerial(Left(sTime, 2), Mid(sTime, 4, 2), Mid(sTime, 7, 2)) + ms
        Case Else
            dTime = 0
    End Select

    Select Case formatDate
        Case "Date: dd/mm/yyyy"
            sDate = Right(DateCell.Value, Len(DateCell.Value) - 6)
            'dDate = DateValue(sDate) 'please read help for DateValue
            dDate = DateSerial(Right(sDate, 4), Mid(sDate, 4, 2), Left(sDate, 2))
        Case Else
            dDate = 0
    End Select

    DateTimeCustomFormat = dTime + dDate

End Function
```

Using as a UDF (user defined function):
[image]

Comment: Hey Axel, thank you for spending your time trying to help me. First, as I see during my code execution, it is actually able to change the value of the input range. By the "TimeCell = Left(TimeCell, Len(TimeCell) - 4)", I change the TimeCell.value. Second, I am really concerned about the problem with system settings too, so your solution with Date- and TimeSerial  is really good, but something is not working. I tried with some data and the results were: dTime=14:55:10, dDate=08/01/2014 and the sum was 08/01/2014  14:55:10.000. However, even Ms = 6.31E-6, the function returns Ms=0. Idea?

Comment: Which was your TimeCell value? "14:55:10:???" The function only works if there are ms in length of 3 digits present.

Comment: TimeCell.value = 15:55:09:546

Comment: Works for me as you see in the image I have added to my answer. The function returns datetime value with milliseconds. How are you calling the function and how are you checking the return value of the function?

Comment: Axel, using as a function in a spreadsheet, it was working perfectly, but being called by a procedure it was not. But I tried one little thing and now it works: DateTimeCustomFormat(xxx) As Double. It is called like "SamList_Sh.Range("D" & cell.Row) = DateTimeCustomFormat(WorkbookOpened.Worksheets(1).Range(RawCyclesTimeRange).Item(1), WorkbookOpened.Worksheets(1).Range(AnalysisDateRange), "hh:mm:ss:ms(xxx)", "Date: dd/mm/yyyy")"

Comment: Actually, I didn't implement a return value checking code, but this is the next step.

Comment: If you are calling the function from a Sub then of course you can also change cell contents and cell formats. This is because the Sub runs outside the sheet calculation context. If you call the function as UDF within a cell formula then you can't do such things. In future you should mention that you want to call the function from a Sub. If I see only a VBA function without any context then I suspect that this shall be a UDF. And I don't think that I am alone with this suspicion.

Comment: Hey Axel, I'm sorry for the missing information, next time I'll try to be clearer. But thank you for your attention and your time, I do appreciate them.